# Symfony2: How to access to service from repository

Tags: php, symfony

I have class ModelsRepository:

```
class ModelsRepository extends EntityRepository
{}
```

And service

```
container_data:
 class:        ProjectName\MyBundle\Common\Container
 arguments:    [@service_container]
```

I want get access from ModelsRepository to service container_data. I can't transmit service from controller used constructor.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried some versions. Problem was solved follows

ModelRepository:

```
class ModelRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    private $container;

    function __construct($container, $em) {
        $class = new ClassMetadata('ProjectName\MyBundle\Entity\ModelEntity');
        $this->container = $container;

        parent::__construct($em, $class);
    }
}
```

security.yml:

```
providers:
    default:
        id: model_auth
```

services.yml

```
model_auth:
    class: ProjectName\MyBundle\Repository\ModelRepository
    argument
```

As a result I got repository with ability use container - as required.
But this realization can be used only in critical cases, because she has limitations for Repository.
Thx 4all.

Answer (score 14):

IMHO, this shouldn't be needed since you may easily break rules like [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

But if you really need it, here's a way to do this:

First, we define a base "ContainerAwareRepository" class which has a call "setContainer"

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    # This is the base class for any repository which need to access container
    acme_bundle.repository.container_aware:
        class: AcmeBundle\Repository\ContainerAwareRepository
        abstract: true
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

The ContainerAwareRepository may looks like this

<kbd>**AcmeBundle\Repository\ContainerAwareRepository.php**</kbd>

```
abstract class ContainerAwareRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Then, we can define our Model Repository.
We use here, the doctrine's `getRepository` method in order to construct our repository

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    acme_bundle.models.repository:
        class: AcmeBundle\Repository\ModelsRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method:  getRepository
        arguments:
            - "AcmeBundle:Models"
        parent:
            acme_bundle.repository.container_aware
```

And then, just define the class

<kbd>**AcmeBundle\Repository\ModelsRepository.php**</kbd>

```
class ModelsRepository extends ContainerAwareRepository
{
    public function findFoo()
    {
        $this->container->get('fooservice');
    }
}
```

In order to use the repository, you absolutely need to call it from the service first.

```
$container->get('acme_bundle.models.repository')->findFoo(); // No errors
$em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Models')->findFoo(); // No errors
```

But if you directly do

```
$em->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Models')->findFoo(); // Fatal error, container is undefined
```

Comment: If my repository has a method searchUserByNameLike and returns an array of Users where the name is like ... and this method has a rule where only admins can see certain user details (like email) (affecting the DQL). Where exactly would I place this function and how do inject a Rules service that's dependent on a User service (the id of the user)? I don't think this is the responsibility of the controller as that just gets the UserRepository (User entity, not User class containing the current user id). This because a search like this could be needed in several controls and control funcions

Comment: @HMR That's a different question. I'd create a *"wrapper"* class which will take `UserRepository` as an argument. Then you'd have a method in your wrapper like `findUsersForUserByNameLike($name, User $user)` which will first check permissions of the given user, build the query and then process the results. For the *"rules"* condition, I'd add an array of `Rule` interface with methods `check(User $user)` and `build(UserRepository $users)` With this, you want to traverse this array and check which rule matches the given user.

Comment: Thanks!! I used the same explanation the use getService on my Service Layer. ;)

Answer (score 7):

You should **never** pass container to the repository, just as you should never let entities handle heavy logic. Repositories have only one purpose - retrieving data from the database. Nothing more (read: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html).

If you need anything more complex than that, you should probably create a separate (container aware if you wish) service for that.

Answer (score 4):

*Are you sure that is a good idea to access service from repo?*

Repositories are designed for custom SQL where, in case of doctrine, doctrine can help you with `find()`,`findOne()`,`findBy()`, [...] "magic" methods.

Take into account to inject your service where you use your repo and, if you need some parameters, pass it directly to repo's method.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a factory service:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

```
//Repository
class ModelsRepositoryFactory
{
    public static function getRepository($entityManager,$entityName,$fooservice)
    {
        $em     = $entityManager;
        $meta   = $em->getClassMetadata($entityName);

        $repository = new ModelsRepository($em, $meta, $fooservice);
        return $repository;
    }
}

//service
AcmeBundle.ModelsRepository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory: [AcmeBundle\Repositories\ModelsRepositoryFactory,getRepository]
        arguments:
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
            - AcmeBundle\Entity\Models
            - @fooservice
```

Answer (score 4):

I strongly agree that this should only be done when absolutely necessary. Though there is a quite simpler approach possible now (tested with Symfony 2.8).

1. Implement in your repository "ContainerAwareInterface"
2. Use the "ContainerAwareTrait"
3. adjust the services.yml

RepositoryClass:

```
namespace AcmeBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareTrait;
use AcmeBundle\Entity\User;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

    use ContainerAwareTrait;

    public function findUserBySomething($param)
    {
        $service = $this->container->get('my.other.service');
    }

}
```

services.yml:

```
acme_bundle.repository.user:
    lazy: true
    class: AcmeBundle\Repository\UserRepository
    factory: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', getRepository]
    arguments:
        - "AcmeBundle:Entity/User"
    calls:
        - method: setContainer
          arguments:
            - '@service_container'
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to inject the service into repository constructor.

```
class ModelsRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  private $your_service;

  public function __construct(ProjectName\MyBundle\Common\Container $service) {
    $this->your_service = $service;
  } 
}
```

Comment: But you don't have direct access to repository constructor so you have to pass service as argument in DIC.

Comment: I written: "I can't transmit service from controller used constructor."

Comment: from my experience if you can not do something it is your architecture fault, not the framework. You're just doings things in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Laurynas Mališauskas answer, to pass service to a constructor make your repository a service too and pass it with arguments:

```
models.repository:
      class: ModelsRepository
      arguments: ['@service_you_want_to_pass']
```