# How to get current User in Repository of Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony

I use the symfony 3 and try to get the current user data in Entity Repository file, but when i used `$this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();`, there is a error message that is can not found the `get function`
So, how to do it?
PS: if in the form type, how to invoke the user data.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Repositories shouldnt known the user. If you need user information you should make a method like this:

```
class YourRepository
{
    public function findSomethingByUser(User $user)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT t FROM AppBundle:Table t '.
                'WHERE t.user > :user'
        )->setParameter('user', $user->getUsername());

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

You can use the repository inside a controller:

```
class MyController
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')
            ->getToken()
            ->getUser();

        $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:EntityName')
            ->findSomethingByUser($user);

        return new Response('foo');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Symfony 3.4 you can use the security Utility Class. This allow you to retrieve the actual user.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
...
class YourRepository
{
    private $security;
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry,  Security $security)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Projekt::class);
         $this->security = $security;
    }
    
    public function findSomethingByUser(User $user)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT t FROM AppBundle:Table t '.
                'WHERE t.user > :user'
        )->setParameter('user', $this->security->getUser());

        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Entity Repository has not Container. You can find solution how do it (as example here [Symfony2: How to access to service from repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971552/symfony2-how-to-access-to-service-from-repository)), but it is not best practice. Repositories have only one goal - work with data from the database. You can pass the user object as parameter for your method.